# wpf window refresh works at first, then stops

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, long-running-processes

I've got a routine that grabs a list of all images in a directory, then runs an MD5 digest on all of them. Since this takes a while to do, I pop up a window with a progress bar. The progress bar is updated by a lambda that I pass in to the long-running routine.

The first problem was that the progress window was never updated (which is normal in WPF I guess). Since WPF lacks a `Refresh()` command I fixed this with a call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. Now the progress bar is updated for a while, then the window stops being updated. The long-running work does eventually finish and the windows go back to normal.

I have already tried a BackgroundWorker and quickly became frustrated by a threading issue related to an event triggered by the long-running process. So if that's really the best solution and I just need to learn the paradigm better, please say so.

But I'd be really much happier with the approach I've got here, except that it stops updating after a bit (for example, in a folder with 1000 files, it might update for 50-100 files, then "hang"). The UI does not need to be responsive during this activity, except to report on progress.

Anyway, here's the code. First the progress window itself:

```
public partial class ProgressWindow : Window
{
    public ProgressWindow(string title, string supertext, string subtext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = title;
        this.SuperText.Text = supertext;
        this.SubText.Text = subtext;
    }

    internal void UpdateProgress(int count, int total)
    {
        this.ProgressBar.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(total);
        this.ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToDouble(count);
        this.SubText.Text = String.Format("{0} of {1} finished", count, total);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
    }

    private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };
}


<Window x:Class="Pixort.ProgressWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Pixort Progress" Height="128" Width="256" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SuperText" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="6"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="SubText" TextAlignment="Right" Padding="6"></TextBlock>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" Height="24" Margin="6"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The long running method (in Gallery.cs):

```
public void ImportFolder(string folderPath, Action<int, int> progressUpdate)
{
    string[] files = this.FileIO.GetFiles(folderPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        // do stuff with the file
        if (null != progressUpdate)
        {
            progressUpdate.Invoke(i + 1, files.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called thusly:

```
 ProgressWindow progress = new ProgressWindow("Import Folder Progress", String.Format("Importing {0}", folder), String.Empty);
 progress.Show();
 this.Gallery.ImportFolder(folder, ((c, t) => progress.UpdateProgress(c, t)));
 progress.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is related to the `DispatcherPriority` in `UpdateProgress`. Changing `DispatcherPriority.Render` to something lower, in my case `DispatcherPriority.Background` did the trick.

Henk's answer lead me to believe that if the message pump is overwhelmed, that it needed help sorting out what to do when. Changing priority seems to be just the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Mate do simple WPF programming by using DataBinding.
Refer MVVM design pattern explaining same.

Bind progressbar value property with some source property defined in DataContext class.
And update source property in dispatcher invoked method.

WPF engine will take care of rest.

You have currently written code wothout any binding...

Comment: Do you know where I can find a working example of this? I tried a lot of different things to get this to work without adding layers of indirection to the code. Every time the bar was not updated at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you do all your work on the Main thread now. That means you are taking away (too much) time from the normal Messagepump (Dispatcher).

The short fix would be an analog to WinForm's Application.DoEvents() but I don't know if there is a WPF equivalent.

The better solution would be to use a Thread, and then the Backgroundworker is the easiest approach. Maybe expand on that event issue.

Comment: Thank you! As you can see your answer helped me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code for performing expected operation.
[Note : Xaml code is not modified]

```
 public partial class ProgressWindow : Window
   {
      public ProgressWindow(string title, string supertext, string subtext)
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         EmptyDelegate = RaiseOnDispatcher;
        this.Title = title; 
        this.SuperText.Text = supertext; 
        this.SubText.Text = subtext; 
      }


    internal void UpdateProgress(int count, int total) 
    {
       this.Dispatcher.Invoke(EmptyDelegate,DispatcherPriority.Render,new object[]{count,total}); 
    }

    private static Action<int, int> EmptyDelegate = null;

    private void RaiseOnDispatcher(int count, int total)
    {
       this.ProgressBar.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(total);
       this.ProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToDouble(count);
       this.SubText.Text = String.Format("{0} of {1} finished", count, total);
    }
   }


   public class Gallery
   {
      static Action<int, int> ActionDelegate=null;
      public static void ImportFolder(string folderPath, Action<int, int> progressUpdate)
      {
         ActionDelegate = progressUpdate;
         BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
         backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
         backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_WorkCompleted);
         backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(folderPath);
         backgroundWorker = null;
      }

     static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
         string folderPath = e.Argument.ToString();
         DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
         FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

         for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
         {
            // do stuff with the file 
            Thread.Sleep(1000);// remove in actual implementation
            if (null != ActionDelegate)
            {
               ActionDelegate.Invoke(i + 1, files.Length);
            }
         }
      }
      static void worker_WorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
         //do after work complete
      }

      public static void Operate()
      {
         string folder = "folderpath";
         ProgressWindow progress = new ProgressWindow("Import Folder Progress", String.Format("Importing {0}", folder), String.Empty);
         progress.Show();
         Gallery.ImportFolder(folder, ((c, t) => progress.UpdateProgress(c, t)));
         progress.Close();
      }


   }
```